# How to split string in excel file with bash script?

Tags: mysql, excel, bash

Good Afternoon

I am trying to develop a bash script which fetches data from a database and then fills an csv file with said data.

So far i have managed to just that but the way the data is presented is not good: all the data is written in one single cell like so:

[image]

and i would like for the data to be presented like this:

[image]

Here is my bash script code so far:

```
#! /bin/bash

currentDate=`date`
mysql -u root -p -D cms -e 'SELECT * from bill' > test_"${currentDate}".csv
```

Can anyone of you tell me what bash commands i can use to achieve the desired result?

Running the cat command of the file gives the following result:

[image]

thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try `'SELECT CONCAT(id, ',', name, ',', mobileNumber, ',', email, ',', date, ',', total, ',', createdBy) from bill'`

Comment: I tried but it still does not give me the result i want, i want the "id" header and its values to be in column A, the "name" header and its values in column B, the mobileNumber header and its value in column C, etc. in other hands i want the data to be delimited by tab

Comment: please update the question with the contents of the file; from your `bash` command line prompt run `cat test_*.csv`, then cut-n-paste the output into your question

Comment: done, i have updated the question with the output of the test csv file when i run the cat command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`, you can change the delimiter from the output displayed in your image (please use text  in the future)

```
$ sed 's/ \+/,/g' test.csv
```

If happy with the output, you can then save the file in place.

```
$ sed -i 's/ \+/,/g' test.csv
```

You should now have the output in different cells when opened in `excel`

Answer (score 0):

Data appears to be tab-delimited (`cat -T test.csv` should show a `^I` between each column); I believe `excel's` default behavior when opening a `.csv` file is to parse the file based on a *comma* delimiter.

To override this default behavior and have `excel` parse the file based on a different delimiter (tab in this case):

- open a clean/new worksheet
- (menu) `DATA` -> `From Text` (file browser should pop up)
- select `test.csv` and hit `Import` (new pop up asks for details on how to parse)
- make sure `Delimited` radio button is chosen (the default), hit `Next >`
- make sure `Tab` checkbox is selected (the default), hit `Next >`
- verify the format in the `Data preview` window (@ bottom of pop up) and if ok then hit 'Finish'

Alternatively, save the file as `test.txt` and upon opening the file with `excel` you should be prompted with the same pop ups asking for parsing details.

I'm not a big `excel` user so I'm not sure if there's a way to get `excel` to automatically parse your files based on tabs (a google/web search will likely provide more help at this point).